# Chip antenna matching of a custom board equipped with a STM32WB55

Tags: circuit-design, rf, stm32, antenna, impedance-matching

I am planning on designing a custom board using a STM32WB55. I have followed the "How to develop RF hardware using STM32WB microcontrollers" (AN5165) Figure 9 design for the RF part, which has a 50 ohm matching circuit consisting in a Pi filter made of a 0.8pF capacitor, an 2.7nH inductor, a 0.3pF capacitor and also a Low Pass Filter (DLF162500LT-5028A1). After these components I plan to use a chip antenna as it should be easier to implement and I have found ANT3216A063R2400A to seem to be fit for this purpose.

The problem I have is that I am not sure if my RF design is good and if it would work. Also, do I have to leave the second pin of the chip antenna floating or should I connect it to ground?
The circuit is like this:

[image: schematic]

The PCB would be something like this:

[image: pcb]

With red being the ground trace and all passive components being in 0603 size. The question is, is the dashed line necessary? I mean, does the second pin of the chip antenna need to be connected to ground or should it be left floating?
Also, are the values for the matching circuit good? Will it work?

Comment: Please provide more details for this.

Comment: I will edit the question in order to be more specific.

Comment: Are you making a RFIC or a PCB? In case of the latter, I'm quite skeptical against a matching design dealing with femto Farads. A slight twist or turn of a trace or a slight solder blob will lead to higher capacitance changes than what you specified these caps for. What about temperature drift? Do you really have this manner of extreme accuracy? Also I suppose specialized NP0 caps will get very expensive.

Comment: Regarding the filter, there's usually some recommendations to put DC blocking caps in series with it on each side. I can't find anything about that in the filter datasheet but maybe you've got a reference design?

Comment: As for chip antennas, I have limited experience, but I believe the other pad is just there to provide stable mechanics and should be left floating.

Comment: I chose that filter because it was recommended in the before-mentioned AN5165 (Figure 9 in the AN). It is my first PCB design which uses RF and also STM32WB55 devices, neither I did not see any DC blocking caps. My main questions still is what I should do with the chip antenna's second pin - should it be left floating, soldered onto my PCB but not connected to anything or should it connect to GND?

Comment: OK, thanks for your input. You were saying that you wouldn't use such small values for the PI filter caps because their value might be offset by unwanted things? What should I use instead?